# Как работает модификатор x в регулярных выражениях PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В доку пишут: x (PCRE_EXTENDED) Если используется данный модификатор, неэкранированные пробелы, символы табуляции и пустой строки будут проигнорированы в шаблоне, если они не являются частью символьного класса.

Ок, вот регулярка https://regex101.com/r/JXpUwE/2

`<m>[a-z]+<\/m>`

Стоит модификатор x но вторую строку где есть пробел она не видит, пробел не игнорируется. Но если я поменяю на `<m>[a-z]+\s<\/m>` то наоборот, вторую строку найдёт первую нет. Так это обычное же поведение... Как работает модификатор x тогда?

Comment: Речь не про пробельные символы в тексте, а про них в регулярке! Вот о чем речь https://regex101.com/r/JXpUwE/3

Comment: @Visman шикарно, спасибо, сделайте ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[x (PCRE_EXTENDED)](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)**  :

> *Если используется данный модификатор, неэкранированные пробелы, символы табуляции и пустой строки будут проигнорированы в шаблоне, если они не являются частью символьного класса. Также игнорируются все символы между неэкранированным символом '#' (если он не является частью символьного класса) и символом перевода строки (включая сами символы '\n' и '#'). Это эквивалентно Perl-модификатору /x, и позволяет размещать комментарий в сложных шаблонах. Замечание: это касается только символьных данных. Пробельные символы не фигурируют в служебных символьных последовательностях, к примеру, в последовательности '(?(', открывающей условную подмаску.*

#### Поясняющие примеры

Необходимо найти подстроку `<b>text</b>` в строке `Example <b>text</b> ...`. Шаблон для этой задачи может выглядеть так: `~<b>[a-z]+</b>~`. Но если добавить в шаблон модификатор "*свободного форматирования*" **x**, то шаблон можно записать так:

```
~<b> [a-z]+ </b>~x
```

И так:

```
~<b> [a-z] + </b>~x
```

И даже так:

```
~
<b> 
[a-z]
+ 
</b>
~x
```

Последний вариант наиболее интересен, т.к. позволяет добавлять прямо в шаблон поясняющие комментарии *(текст после символа `#`)*:

```
~
<b>    # Соответствие открывающему тегу b
[a-z]  # за которым следует последовательность символов от a до z
+      # Обязательный максимальный (жадный) квантификатор
</b>   # Соответствие закрывающему тегу b
~x
```

В сочетании с PHP код примет такой вид:

```
$str = 'Example <b>text</b> ...';

$patt = '~
    <b>    # Соответствие открывающему тегу b
    [a-z]  # за которым следует последовательность символов от a до z
    +      # Обязательный максимальный (жадный) квантификатор
    </b>   # Соответствие закрывающему тегу b
~x';

preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

---

Стоит отметить, что для добавления небольшого поясняющего комментария в pcre-шаблон, не обязательно использовать модификатор `x`. Можно использовать синтаксис интервального изменения режимов `(?...:)`, и тогда шаблон примет следующий вид:

```
$str = 'Example <b>text</b> ...';

$patt = '~<b>[a-z](?#:Это символьный класс)+</b>~';

preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Если используется данный модификатор, неэкранированные пробелы,
>   символы табуляции и пустой строки будут проигнорированы в **шаблоне**

Речь про шаблон регулярного выражения, а не текста.

К вашему примеру

```
<m>   [a-z]+\s*     <\/m>
```